# "In"-Usage in the sentence as a Preposition?

Tags: word-usage

" Oliver is in the garden." Here "**in**" joins Oliver and garden.

Am i correct the preposition "in" here joins two Nouns (Oliver and garden.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantically, yes, "in" expresses the relationship between Oliver and the garden.

Grammatically, no, in English, "in" has no grammar connection to Oliver.

Answer (score 1):

The word "in" heads the prepositional phrase "in the garden".

The word "is" links the subject "Oliver" to the prepositional phrase "in the garden".

Comment: "in" I think joins the two nouns "Oliver" & "in the garden" by telling the relationship between Oliver & the garden?(plz clarify)

Comment: No.  preposition don't "join", They head prepositional phrases.  I think my description of the grammar is as clear as I can make it.